# How to use disk files to replace memfile?

Tags: ndvi, rasterio, memory, sentinel

I am trying to collect Sentinel images and compute their NDVI which is done quite simply.
However, I need to check determine all shapely multipolygons and map a NDVI value for each.
I've decided to use only a set of 8 ranges of NDVI.
So in my function, I want it to return a list of tuples (multipolygon, corresponding ndvi_value) whose length is 8 here for instance.
I am using a code found on the internet but it uses so much memory (more than 16 GB at least) so I cannot run it locally or even on some servers which are not powerful enough.
(It worked once on a powerful server but thus it made the server unusable for my colleagues).
Here the main part of the code:

```
 with MemoryFile() as memfile:    
            with memfile.open( **meta) as dataset:
                print("start image")
                dataset.write(image)
                print("end image")
                dataset.close()
            
            # Extract bbox-ed image
            # with memfile.open() as dataset:
            #     out_image, out_transform = mask(dataset, parcelle_bbox_data_crs_proj,crop=True)
            #     #out_image, out_transform = raster_geometry_mask(dataset, parcelle_bbox_data_crs_proj,crop=True)
            #     out_meta = dataset.meta.copy()
            #     out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
            #                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
            #                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
            #                 "transform": out_transform})

            # Resample data
            with memfile.open() as dataset:
                out_image = dataset.read(
                    out_shape=(
                        dataset.count,
                        int(dataset.height * upscale_factor),
                        int(dataset.width * upscale_factor)
                    ),
                    resampling=Resampling.bilinear
                )
              

                # scale image transform
                out_transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
                    (dataset.width / out_image.shape[-1]),
                    (dataset.height / out_image.shape[-2])
                )
                out_meta = dataset.meta.copy()
                out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                            "height": out_image.shape[1],
                            "width": out_image.shape[2],
                            "transform": out_transform})

                dataset.close()


            with MemoryFile() as memfile:    
                with memfile.open(**out_meta) as dataset:
                    print("start out_image")
                    dataset.write(out_image)
                    print("end out_image")
                    
                # Extract image with parcelle boundaries
                with memfile.open() as dataset:
                    # out_image, out_transform = mask(dataset, parcelle_data_crs_proj,crop=True)
                    out_image, out_transform = mask(dataset, parcelle_data_crs_proj,crop=True)
                    out_meta = dataset.meta.copy()
                    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                                "height": out_image.shape[1],
                                "width": out_image.shape[2],
                                "transform": out_transform})

                    if out_image.dtype.kind == 'f':
                        out_image[out_image==0] = np.nan

                with rio.open(out_filepath, "w", compress = "LZW", **out_meta) as dest:
                    print("start out_image2")
                    dest.write(out_image)
                    print("end out_image2")
```

The program uses memfile to do the computations and it consumes far too much RAM.
How could I replace all the memfiles by disk files with open?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I get the following error : with open('media/lao/JM/temp.tif', 'w' **meta) as dataset:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'dict'

Comment: You need to separate all args with a comma `with open('path/to/temp.tif', 'w', **meta) as dataset:`

Comment: Yes that's what I've done but I get :  open() takes at most 8 arguments (10 given).
So I'm trying with rasterio.open now.
I've edited my post so maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, it's rasterio.open (open is for normal python files)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now !